# Android library update cause build time error

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-lifecycle, android-library, android-viewmodel

I have a pretty weird issue. As soon as I update my dependencies this error occures at build time.

```
e: error: Cannot figure out how to save this field into database. You can consider adding a type converter for it. - mBagOfTags in androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel
e: error: Cannot find getter for field. - mBagOfTags in androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel
e: error: Cannot find getter for field. - mCleared in androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel
e: error: Cannot find setter for field. - mBagOfTags in androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel
e: error: Cannot find setter for field. - mCleared in androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel
e: error: Cannot figure out how to read this field from a cursor. - mBagOfTags in androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel
e: error: Cannot find setter for field. - mBagOfTags in androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel
e: error: Cannot find setter for field. - mCleared in androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel
```

I am using `Material` 1.0.0 but I need to update it. I can update until [1.1.0-alpha05](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/releases/tag/1.1.0-alpha05). After that version like 1.1.0-alpha06 causes this error. I've checked release notes and nothing related changed at [1.1.0-alpha06](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/releases/tag/1.1.0-alpha06). It is the same for `AppCompat` version now it is 1.0.2 and as soon as I update it, this error occurs again. I've tried to update `core-ktx` and the result is the same...

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So I've found out that one of my entity class extends ViewModel. Removing it solved the problem. Just check your entity class.

Thanks.